# What is exp(O(n)) and how does it differ to O(exp(n))?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, exp

In a recent lecture, we were told that an algorithm has a time complexity of `exp(O(n))`, and that that was different to a time complexity of `O(exp(n))`. I am interested in the following:

1. How do we read a time complexity of `exp(O(n))` and what does it imply?
2. What is the difference between an `exp(O(n))` and `O(exp(n))` time complexity?

I assume the first question will answer the second one as well, but an explicit answer would be very appreciated.

---

To clarify, the time complexities we were presented with were actually in Big-Theta, not Big-O, notation, but I assumed the same relevant properties would hold for both, and this would be a more useful way of phrasing the question (since I feel like people search for Big-O more than they do for Big-Theta).

For those who are curious, the algorithm in question is the brute-force method for finding a minimum cost path between nodes on a regular lattice. We were comparing it to a the much more efficient (`Θ(n^2)`) dynamic programming approach. The module I am taking is on computational biology, and the topic is global sequence matching for DNA and proteins.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way to understand what exp(*O*(*n*)) means is to demonstrate the difference:

If we assume we are working in base *e*, then exp(*O*(*n*)) can be written as *e*<sup>*f*(*n*)</sup>, where *f*(*n*) ∈ *O*(*n*). Notice that both *n* and 2*n* are *O*(*n*), however, when they are in the exponent, things are different: *O*(*e*<sup>*n*</sup>) ≠ *O*(*e*<sup>2*n*</sup>), because *O*(*e*<sup>2*n*</sup>) = *O*((*e*<sup>2</sup>)<sup>*n*</sup>). The exponential expression has a different base, therefore belonging to a different class of functions.

Thus, exp(*O*(*n*)) is a different class of functions than *O*(exp(*n*)), as the latter requires that the asymptotic growth follows that of *e*<sup>*n*</sup>. (Naturally, if our base is something other than *e*, the same argument still applies.)

An important result is that exp(*O*(*n*)) includes functions that grow faster than any function in *O*(exp(*n*)), and thus *O*(exp(*n*)) ⊆ exp(*O*(*n*)).

What might be the source of the confusion is that exp(*O*(*n*)) is actually the same class as *O*(exp(*O*(*n*))). However, as exp(*O*(*n*)) is already a class of functions, there is no need to add the wrapping *O*. Because *c*·exp(*f*(*n*)) grows slower than exp(*c*·*f*(*n*)), thus *c*·exp(*f*(*n*)) ∈ exp(*O*(*n*)) for *f*(*n*) ∈ *O*(*n*).

Comment: Just because it is a source of confusion.  Because 2 < e, 2^n ∈ O(e^n) ⊆e^(O(n)). But because e < 4, 4^n is not in O(e^n).  However 4^n ∈ e^(O(n)).